# weblogic to websphere migration problem

Tags: migration, weblogic

currently we are using Weblogic application server and we are planning to migrate from Weblogic to WebSphere.
Could anyone please let us know what can be the problems occurs during this migration.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on if your applications currently use any Weblogic-specific features. If it's a custom application then you have to be familiar with the programming. More than likely, if it's a Spring-based application you will face minimal issues redeploying to a different container. If it's a 3rd party application you'll want to check the manual to see any container specific instructions.

Take this with a big grain of salt but usually going from Weblogic to WebSphere is less of a hassle than vice versa because Weblogic has less custom 'hooks' and features than WebSphere, for the most part it (Weblogic) just does a really good job of following the Java EE spec whereas WebSphere takes a ton of liberties with it.

As an example: WebSphere supports Shared Session Context between multiple applications (which is not a part of the Java EE spec) and if your apps utilize this they'll probably need some refactoring.